# Key Performance Indicators for HR

Tags: human-resources, performance-reviews, performance

I'm currently working in a tech based startup as a HR Manager and it's been only 5 months that I got into this role.

My manager is asking me to set up the KPIs for HR and come up with performance tracking metrics for the same?

Could you help me to set KPIs for HR and give me some tips regarding the same.

I'm looking for quantitative goals. 
TIA.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not specific to HR and is applicable to all KPI for any team  :

Why a KPI? -> to maximize the productivity/quality/delay/etc of the team to deliver on target.

How to definine a KPI -> first you need to identify what are the objectives of the team ( for HR : recruting whitout too much delay, contain the salary mass, organizee the office life, time to settle legal issues, etc).

Note : as you will need to explain to your boss how you set up the KPI, you can do a PPT slide with a frame : on the left all the input of the team ( order from CEO, request of hiring from other department, law of the country, etc) and on the right the output (how many people hired, turnover, no legal complain). You should have a KPI on each output ( and input if you want to justify why there in an issue an on output that is not caused your team)

How to set a KPI : for each KPI you need to set level of achievement with a value (low turnover is good, high turnover is bad) (1 month to find a candidate is good, 1 year in bad)

How to weight a KPI -> if you have 5 KPI you can weight them each 20% if you think they have the exact same importance. But usually each KPI will have a different weight. ( it is more importnat to follow the KPI of the recruting process timeframe than the KPI of cofee machine downtime - or is it? :) ).

Knowing that you can EDIT your post, propose your set of KPI, and we can review it.

Comment: Be careful what you set as the KPI. People tend to see these as requirements for their job and will strive to increase the numbers in the short term without thinking of long term consequences for the company. Example: Time to Settle legal issues. We can get this number down by making sure we settle fast not concentrating on the cost to the company (as this is not a KPI).